# How to change the number of rows displayed in the Data output tab in pgadmin4

Tags: pgadmin-4

I am using [pgAdmin4 6.13](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/).

Since a few versions, it now limits the number of resulting features to 1'000 in the "Data output" tab after running a query, e.g.:

[image: paginated number of resulting rows in the Data output tab in pgAdmin4 6.12]

So, not all the features are displayed at once (as it was the case with older versions).
It seems paginated now, which is a good idea but I cannot figure out how to see the next 1'000 features.

But this is especially painful when one want to display all ([PostGIS](https://postgis.net/)) geometric data from a table (using the small 'map' button close to the name of the geometry columns) because it creates holes everywhere on the map if you want to display them all (provided you have more than 1'000 features of course).

Is there a way to tweak the number of resulting rows in the "Data output" tab?

I'd like to set this number to 'unlimited' in my particular case.

Comment: There should be a drop down in the toolbar to set the limit

Comment: I cannot see such drop down. A screenshot of your 6.12 would be nice to have.